# How to pass a selected value in a dropdown list in one modal to another dropdown list in another modal t

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two dropdown lists with same values in two different modals. One is in Insert modal and the other one is in the Update modal. What i want to do is to pass the selected value of the dropdown list in Insert modal and when I open the Update modal I want that value to be selected in the dropdown list in that modal.

Is there Anyway I can do this ? With Bootstrap, jquery, javascript ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried this

```
    var countryInsertID = document.getElementById('countryInsert'), 
        countryUpdate = document.getElementById('countryUpdate'), 
        option; 
        countryInsertID.onchange = function () { 
            option = document.createElement('option'); 
            option.value = this.value; 
            option.text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; 
            countryUpdate.appendChild(option); 
            countryInsertID.removeChild(this.options[this.selectedIndex]); 
        }
```

Comment: please show us what u have tried so far :)

Comment: I have tried to use the solution form this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911011/how-to-store-value-from-one-dropdown-list-to-another-dropdown-list

Comment: Also all the other values that are inside the input types are being passed fine, I just can pass the value of the dropdown lists.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `localStorage`

```
var countryInsert=document.getElementById('countryInsert')
var countryUpdate=document.getElementById('countryUpdate')

countryInsert.onchange = function() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('selected', countryInsert.value);
}
```

When you show the Update Modal

```
countryUpdate.value = window.localStorage.getItem('selected');
```

---

**Update**

If you just have the modals on the same page, in hidden  as the "bootstrap way" you not need all that - just

```
<script>
    var countryInsert=document.getElementById('countryInsert')
    var countryUpdate=document.getElementById('countryUpdate')
    countryInsert.onchange = function() {
        countryUpdate.value = countryInsert.value;
    }
</script>
```

-- at the bottom of your page. Then the countryUpdate `<select>` will always be in sync with the countryInsert `<select>`

Comment: Looks like this could be it. Could you be more specific about where should I put which variable and function. Because I have two different modals and countryInsert id is located in Insert modal and countryUpdate id is located in Update modal. Im sorry if this is a stubpid request, Im just new to the programming world, this would help a lot.

Comment: They are both located at the same page I assume? In hidden <div>'s? I think of the "standard" bootstrap way to do it...? Is the modal content destroyed when you close them?